# Does a Druid's bite when wild shaped into a dire rat inflict disease?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wild-shape, disease

When a druid wild shapes into other forms, they get those attacks.

In this case, when a druid becomes a [dire rat](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/rat.html#rat-dire), do they gain the filth fever disease on bite attacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At 4th level, a druid gains the ability to turn herself into any small or Medium animal and back again once per day. Her options for new forms include all creatures with the animal type. This ability functions **like the Beast Shape I spell**, except as noted here. The effect lasts for 1 hour per druid level, or until she changes back. Changing form (to animal or back) is a standard action and doesn’t provoke an attack of opportunity. The form chosen must be that of an animal the druid is familiar with.
>
> ...
>
> At 6th level, a druid can use wild shape to change into a Large or Tiny animal or a Small elemental. When taking the form of an animal, a druid’s wild shape now functions as Beast Shape II. When taking the form of an elemental, the druid’s wild shape functions as Elemental Body I.
>
> ...
>
> At 8th level, a druid can use wild shape to change into a Huge or Diminutive animal, a Medium elemental, or a Small or Medium plant creature. When taking the form of animals, a druid’s wild shape now functions as Beast Shape III. When taking the form of an elemental, the druid’s wild shape now functions as Elemental Body II. When taking the form of a plant creature, the druid’s wild shape functions as Plant Shape I.

Then the text for Beast Shape I

> When you cast this spell, you can assume the form of any Small or Medium creature of the animal type. If the form you assume has any of the following abilities, you gain the listed ability: climb 30 feet, fly 30 feet (average maneuverability), swim 30 feet, darkvision 60 feet, low-light vision, and scent.
>
> Small animal: If the form you take is that of a Small animal, you gain a +2 size bonus to your Dexterity and a +1 natural armor bonus.
>
> Medium animal: If the form you take is that of a Medium animal, you gain a +2 size bonus to your Strength and a +2 natural armor bonus.

Beast Shape II

> ...you gain the listed ability: climb 60 feet, fly 60 feet (good maneuverability), swim 60 feet, darkvision 60 feet, low-light vision, scent, grab, pounce, and trip.

Beast Shape III

> ...you gain the listed ability: burrow 30 feet, climb 90 feet, fly 90 feet (good maneuverability), swim 90 feet, blindsense 30 feet, darkvision 60 feet, low-light vision, scent, constrict, ferocity, grab, jet, poison, pounce, rake, trample, trip, and web.

Disease is not listed under the abilities granted by Beast Form I, II, or, III. You, therefore, do not get it when you wild shape.

Comment: Neither is getting the base land speed of the form, but that is mentioned under the transmutation/polymorph rules.

Comment: "Disease" is an extraordinary power, like a wolf's "trip" ability on his attacks, not just a weird type of natural attack. However it seems fair to make it available with Beast Shape III as you can get "poison" then which is very similar.

Comment: Fering: a fair point. You're certainly welcome to make that case if you think it will hold water in your game.

Comment: Anne: also a good argument; likely worth taking up with a GM who is amenable to that sort of house rule.

Answer (score 0):

## Maybe

Is Disease an Extraordinary Special Ability that depends on form?  If so, the GM may or may not permit you to gain the ability.  If not, then no.

> Your new form might restore a number of these abilities if they are possessed by the new form.

(from the polymorph subschool rules)

In most settings, diseases are not the result of the form of the rat but rather something external to it, so most of the time the answer will be 'no'.